Creating K8s Secrets and Jobs dynamically - replacing sensitive placeholder values
In my Github Actions workflow, I am trying to dynamically create one K8s Job, and K8s Secret or Configmap per schema, in a list that I’m fetching from Snowflake.
I’m looking for the best way is to accomplish this. Right now, I have a Workflow which fetches the list of schemas in one step, then in another step, I’m iterating over that list, and using the schema name to replace some values in the Secret and Job template, then applying each one to do a data ingestion task.
The problem I’m facing is with replacing the ${SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY} and ${SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS} in the stringData section of my Secret. I’m hitting errors like   "sed: -e expression #4, char 64: unterminated `s' command"
coming from the sed command in the run section of my Workflow step, which I’m using to try to replace the values:
sed "s#\${SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY}#${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY }}#g" "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-template.yml" > "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml"  

I think this error is caused by Github Actions encoding the snowflake password as “*****” but I am not sure. Also, it seems like there should be a better way to replace these values. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Newbie here btw if you couldn’t tell.
Here is the relevant snippet from the workflow as-is for reference:
- name: Get vault secrets  
        uses: "redacted"  
        with:  
          vault-url: "redacted"  
          role-id: ${{ secrets.VAULT_PROD_ROLE_ID }}  
          secret-id: ${{ secrets.VAULT_PROD_SECRET_ID }}  
          auth-namespace: "redacted"  
          secret-namespace: "redacted"  
          secret-list: |  
            "redacted" 'rsa_key.p8' | SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY;  
            "redacted" private_key_pass | SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS;  
  
      - name: Authenticate K8s / Setup kubectl  
        uses: "redacted"  
        with:  
          environment: dev  
          vault-role-id: ${{ secrets.VAULT_PROD_ROLE_ID }}  
          vault-secret-id: ${{ secrets.VAULT_PROD_SECRET_ID }}  
  
      - name: Fetch schema list  
        id: fetch-schemas  
        run: |  
          python3 k8s/fetch-schemas.py  
        env:  
          SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY }}  
          SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS: ${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS }}  
          SNOWFLAKE_USER: "redacted"  
          SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT: "redacted"  
          SNOWFLAKE_ROLE: "redacted"  
          SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE: "redacted"  
  
      - name: Loop through schemas and deploy  
        shell: bash
        run: |  
          SCHEMA_LIST=$(echo '${{ steps.fetch-schemas.outputs.schema_list }}' | jq -r '.[]')  
          for SCHEMA in $SCHEMA_LIST; do  
            echo "Processing schema: $SCHEMA"  
            export SCHEMA_NAME=$SCHEMA  
            SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME=$(echo $SCHEMA | sed 's/[_.]/-/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')  

            # Echo the sanitized schema name  
            echo "Sanitized schema name: $SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME"
 
            # Fetch secrets from the vault step  
            SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY="${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY }}"
            SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS="${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS }}"

            echo "Current directory:"
            echo $(pwd)
            echo "Contents of k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-template.yml:"
            echo $(cat k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-template.yml)
           
            sed -e 's#\${SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME}#'"$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME"'#g' -e 's#\${SCHEMA_NAME}#'"$SCHEMA_NAME"'#g' -e 's#\${SNOWFLAKE_ENV}#'"$ENV_CODE"'#g' "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-template.yml" > "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml"  

            # Debug: Check the contents of the generated configmap file  
            echo "Contents of $(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml:"  
            cat $(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml  

            # Delete existing Configmap if it exists  
            kubectl delete configmap sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME --ignore-not-found  

            # Create Configmap
            kubectl apply -f $(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml

            # Replace placeholder in Job file and apply  
            sed "s#\${SCHEMA_NAME}#$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME#g" "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-job-template.yml" > "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-job-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml" 
  
            # Debug: Check the contents of the generated job file  
            echo "Contents of k8s/sf-to-console-job-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml:"  
            cat k8s/sf-to-console-job-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml  

            # Delete existing Job if it exists  
            kubectl delete job sf-to-console-job-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME --ignore-not-found  
            
            kubectl apply -f k8s/sf-to-console-job-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml  
          done  
  



Your shell code has several issues. Copy/paste just your shell code into http://shellcheck.net, add a bash shebang (#!/bin/bash) at the top, and then fix the issues that shellcheck will tell you about. Once you've done that, then let us know if you still have a problem (and post the shellcheck-clean code).

The issue you are facing is caused by the multiline value of the private key ${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY }}. sed can not handle unescaped multiline values for substitution. This value needs to be represented as a single line where each end of line character 0x0A is encoded as "\n". The easiest way to do this is by using awk:
SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY=$(echo -n '${{ env.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY }}' | awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}')

Having escaped end of lines, you can now perform substitution:
sed "s#\${SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY}#$SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY#g" "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-template.yml" > "$(pwd)/k8s/sf-to-console-configmap-$SANITIZED_SCHEMA_NAME.yml"  

It is even simpler to create a config map directly from a private key file:
kubectl delete configmap my-config
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=name=private-key.pem

Here name is the name of the entry in the config map and private-key.pem is the private key file name.
You can add as many entries as you need in a single command line. These entries can be literals provided on the command line
--from-literal=name=value

or they can come from files as in the case of the private key above.
